# Is RAID 170 a Proprietary RAID Config or a Combination of Traditional RAID Configs?

Tags: raid, cisco, lsi, megaraid

I acquired a Cisco c240 M4 with twenty-four (24) 800 GB SATA SSD. I requested the engineers configure the disks in two separate RAID 10 arrays (18 + 4), plus with a hot spare for each. The LSI MegaRAID Storage Manager was installed and I used it to review the settings, and came across the following.

[image: LSI MegaRaid screenshot]

Since it's not a published RAID config like RAID 5, 6 or 10, is this RAID 170 configuration proprietary to Cisco equipment or the RAID controller utilized by LSI or merely a combo of multiple RAID levels like 1+0=10?

Comment: I'm guessing it's proprietary. I've never seen a RAID 7 in the wild, nor do I expect to. It's an old proprietary level that isn't used anymore. Maybe ask Cisco about this? They'd have a better idea.

Comment: The company called RAIDIX claims to have RAID-7 (with 3 parity drives) systems. However this is different. Apparently there are 3 arrays aggregated as 1 logical drive, do the separate arrays have a RAID level? I would expect that.

Comment: Dividing the size of the Virtual disk (6.5 TB) in 3, I found that each Array is 2,1 TB, wich is exactly the capacity of 3 disks. So this would be a nonsensical config of  a RAID-0 of 3 arrays, each array being a RAID-10+dedicated spare. Crazy  stuff :)